# How to fix connection error between amazon developer console and visual studio code?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I can't download the profile code created in the Alexa Skill Toolkit, whenever I try to download it to the IDE I'm asked for a credential that didn't appear before.
The error shown below is this:

It is expected that when downloading the skill connected to the amazon developer account, the extension in visual studio code creates a remote connection between the IDE and the skill hosted on amazon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that you would like to know what credentials to use from VS Code. In this case, use the following procedure to log into your Amazon developer account from VS Code.

1.In the activity bar, click the Alexa icon.

2.On the Sign in page, click Sign in. The Amazon developer account sign in page launches in your browser.

3.After signing in, return to VS Code.

For more information: https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/ask-toolkit/get-started-with-the-ask-toolkit-for-visual-studio-code.html